# JSP class instance members

Tags: java, jsp, singleton

Suppose there is a JSP with the following content

```
<%@ page import="com.example.MyClass" %>
<%
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
%>
```

It is translated in something like

```
  public void _jspService(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws java.io.IOException, ServletException {

      // ...

      MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
```

Is there a way to declare myClass as compiled JSP class instance member, not as a local member of the instance method, in order to avoid repetitive object creation without redesigning MyClass as a singleton?

I want to have something like

```
private MyClass myClass = new MyClass();

public void _jspService(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws java.io.IOException, ServletException {

    // ...
```

Can it be declared as static member?

Comment: You might want to look at the `application scope`.  From http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1009 :  "**Application Scope**

Objects with application scope are accessible from JSP pages that reside in the same application. This creates a global object that's available to all pages."

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned here don't use instance variables in JSP but instead rely on scope variables.

But here is an example how to declare instance variables in JSP:

```
<%!
private MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
%>
```

Anything inside `<%!...%>` block will be written as JSP compiled class body.